# Ubuntu Linux: Change settings for mutt and/or sendmail

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sendmail, mutt

Inherited system setup. Ubuntu using mutt and sendmail to send emails is currently using on-premise Exchange Sever that is scheduled to be phased out. I have to change it so that it uses a builtin mail-server on our firewall instead. How does one change this?

Answer (score 0):

With a standard ubuntu mutt and sendmail installation this is most likely configured in /etc/mail/sendmail.mc with the name SMART_HOST

After changing sendmail.mc you will need to run a make (to 'compile' the configuration) and restart sendmail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I neither have that "sendmail.mc" directory nor a "SMART_HOST" file anywhere on my system, so..not standard then I guess.